# Pointer never reaches null in linked list deep copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am currently building a linked list class called Sequence. There are four private nodes- headPtr, tailPtr, cursor (current node), and precursor (previous node).

My copy constructor worked fine when the cursor was the last item in the list, but when the cursor is in the middle for some reason the function never exits the while loop.

Here is the copy constructor:

```c
Sequence::Sequence(const Sequence& copyMe) {
        copy(copyMe);
    }

void Sequence::copy(const Sequence& copyMe) {

        numitems = 0;

        if (copyMe.headPtr == nullptr) {
            cursor = precursor = headPtr = tailPtr = nullptr;
        }
        else {

            // allocate a new node for the new sequence
            node* newPtr = new node;
            newPtr -> data = copyMe.headPtr -> data;
            numitems++;

            // start the new sequence with this node
            headPtr = newPtr;
            precursor = nullptr;
            cursor = headPtr;
            tailPtr = headPtr;

            // create a node to traverse the origin sequence
            node* originPtr = copyMe.headPtr -> next;

            while (originPtr != nullptr) {

                // add node to the new list, make it the current, & assign data
                newPtr->next = new node;
                newPtr = newPtr->next;
                newPtr->data = originPtr->data;
                numitems++;

                // Correct cursor and precursor positions
                if(originPtr == copyMe.cursor) {
                    this->cursor = newPtr;
                }
                else if (originPtr == copyMe.precursor) {
                    this->precursor = newPtr;
                }
                originPtr = originPtr->next;

                // if the thing being copied is the last thing, make it tailptr    
                if (originPtr == nullptr) {

                    tailPtr = newPtr->next;
                    cout << "tail assigned" << endl;

                    newPtr->next = nullptr;
                    originPtr = nullptr;
                }         
            }     
        }
    }
```

And here is the driver program:

```c
    const size_t TESTSIZE = 30;
    Sequence original; // A Sequence that we'll copy.
    double items[2 * TESTSIZE];
    size_t i;

    // Set up the items array to conatin 1...2*TESTSIZE.
    for (i = 1; i <= 2 * TESTSIZE; i++)
        items[i - 1] = i;

    // This section works fine //
    // Test copying of an empty Sequence. After the copying, we change original.
    cout << "Copy constructor test: for an empty Sequence." << endl;
    Sequence copy1(original);
    original.attach(1); // Changes the original Sequence, but not the copy.

    // Test copying of a Sequence with current item at the tail.
    cout << "Copy constructor test: for a Sequence with cursor at tail." << endl;
    for (i = 2; i <= 2 * TESTSIZE; i++) {
        original.attach(i);
    }
    Sequence copy2(original);
    original.remove_current(); 
    original.start();
    original.advance();
    original.remove_current(); // Delete 2 from original, but not the copy.

    // This section gets stuck in the while loop of my copy constructor //
    // Test copying of a Sequence with cursor near the middle.
    cout << "Copy constructor test: with cursor near middle." << endl;
    original.insert(2);
    for (i = 1; i < TESTSIZE; i++)
        original.advance();
    // Cursor is now at location [TESTSIZE] (counting [0] as the first spot).
    Sequence copy3(original);
```

I am confused why the position of the cursor is affecting the advancement of `originPtr`, and why `originPtr` doesn't get to null and have the tail assigned. I tried outputting what it pointed to, but it seems like its just continuously advancing through memory slots in a circular fashion. Once it reaches 60, it goes right back to adding in from 2 rather than terminating.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
This is what the output looks like when it works with cursor at the end after adding some cout statements:

```
Copy constructor test: for a Sequence with cursor at tail.
Copy constructor test: for a Sequence with cursor at tail.
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00140 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00000
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00010 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00020
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00020 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00030
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00030 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00040
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00040 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00050
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00050 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00060
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00060 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00070
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00070 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00080
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00080 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00090
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00090 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000a0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce000a0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000b0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce000b0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000c0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce000c0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000d0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce000d0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000e0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce000e0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000f0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce000f0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00100
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00100 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00110
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00110 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00120
NULL REACHED
tail assigned
```

versus the next test where the cursor is in the middle

```
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcf00030 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00000
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcf00040 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00020
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcf00050 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00030
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcf00060 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00040
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcf00070 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00050
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcf00080 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00060
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcf00090 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00070
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00010 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00080
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00120 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00090
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00150 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000a0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00160 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000b0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00170 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000c0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00180 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000d0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00190 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000e0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00120 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd000f0
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00130 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00100
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00140 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00110
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00150 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00120
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00160 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00150
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00170 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00160
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00180 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00170
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00190 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00180
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce001a0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dcd00190
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce001b0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00120
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce001c0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00130
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce001d0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00140
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce001e0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00150
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce001f0 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00160
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00200 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00170
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00210 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00180
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00220 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00190
newPtr is: 0x7fa6dce00230 and originPtr is: 0x7fa6dce001a0
// and so on forever because its stuck in a loop and endlessly advancing somehow
```

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code, **line-by-line**, with a debugger, while observing the values of every variable, at each execution step, to see if they match your expectations? 2) Please provide [mre].

Comment: Reduce the TESTSIZE variable and step through your program in visual studio. That always helps me find what's wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't be to sure that the problem is the copy constructor (it seems fine to me and as you said I don't think the position of the cursor should make any difference). But you modified `original` quite a bit since your last call to the copy constructor, so maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @n314159 I have omitted the section that tests the statements following copy for the cursor at tail test, since they all succeed. Additionally, all of these functions are used in earlier tests that succeeded as well

Comment: Code appears to be clean,
1) Reduce the test input size 2) try to run the test independently 3) check the behavior of originPtr.precursor  and originPtr.cursor after operation performed after `remove_current`

Comment: One little problem is that if it surprisingly happens that `copyMe.cursor` and `copyMe.precursor` point to the same node, you will only set `this->cursor`, ignoring `this->precursor` due to the `if/else` exclusion.

Comment: The `originPtr = nullptr;` assignment near the end is pointless since it's in an `if` that is guarded by the condition `originPtr == nullptr`.

Comment: If the `while` loop doesn't terminate, it's because the original list has a cycle. The problem is in the code which constructed that list, or else in code which mutated it afterward. This function doesn't do either of these things with the original list, and doesn't seem to be introducing cycles in the newly copied list, so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right syntax for a copy construcutor is:

```
Sequence::Sequence(const Sequence& copyMe) {...}
```

You have written:

```
void Sequence::copy(const Sequence& copyMe) {...}
```

This means that you defined a member function instead of constructor. So your constructor is never called. When you create copy1, copy2, and copy3 the default constructor is used.

**UPDATE**

```
if (originPtr == nullptr) {

  tailPtr = newPtr->next; // newPtr->next is not initialized here
                          // consider tailPtr = newPtr instead
  cout << "tail assigned" << endl;

  newPtr->next = nullptr; // good
  originPtr = nullptr;    // originPtr is nullptr here because of if condition
}
```

**UPDATE2**

I can not check your implementation of moving current and previous position of the cursor but please note that in your copy constructor you assume that current and previous pointers are always different.

```
else if (originPtr == copyMe.precursor) { // consider removing 'else' here
```

**UPDATE3**

```
Sequence copy2(original);
original.remove_current(); // here you remove the last element
```

It looks like the problem is in the `remove_current()`. The loop in the constructor does not depend of the cursor position. But it depends of node->next values of the original sequence. So mistakes in creating copies will not cause the infinite loop. The only reason for infinite loop is bad-formed original sequence. I suspect that you forgot to update the `next` value of the last node after removing the last element from the sequence. I can not proof my words until you publish the code of remove_current().

**UPDATE4**

```
void Sequence::remove_current() {
        if (is_item()) {

            node* temp;
            temp = cursor;

            if (cursor == headPtr && cursor == tailPtr) {
                cursor = nullptr;
                precursor = nullptr;
                headPtr = nullptr;
                tailPtr = nullptr;
            }
            else if (cursor == headPtr) {
                headPtr = cursor->next;
                cursor = headPtr;
                precursor = nullptr;
            }
            else {
                if (cursor == tailPtr) {
                    precursor->next = nullptr;
                    tailPtr = precursor;
                    cursor = precursor;
                    if (precursor == headPtr) {
                        precursor = nullptr;
                    }
                    else {
                        for(precursor = headPtr; precursor->next->next; precursor = precursor->next);
                    }
                }
                else {      
                    precursor->next = cursor->next;
                    cursor = cursor->next;

                }    
            }
            delete temp;
            numitems--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well the actual copy constructor is ```Sequence::Sequence(const Sequence& copyMe) {
        copy(copyMe);
    }```, it calls this function is all

Comment: that fixes the loop issue, but causes a segmentation fault. See output: https://pastebin.com/B0HTgQvu

Comment: I've changed it to an `if` instead of an `else if`, but that alone didn't make a difference. Here is the `remove_current():` and the fixes to the `copy`: https://pastebin.com/J2PiNPWQ. No segmentation fault, but still in the loop

Comment: @NP2000 My suspicions came true. Please see update 4